# C++ funcion getch(), como puedo saber los valores numéricos de cada tecla?

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo con estas funciones y ya tengo la sintaxis hecha, pero no se como puedo saber los valores que da una tecla al ser pulsada para asignarlo a un valor.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

para la próxima te sugiero adjuntes el código, he hecho ese código de afán, ahí te queda guardado el valor obtenido del `getch` en la variable, `int a` hace que te quede con el valor numérico que representa el carácter en ASCII si quieres lo puedes cambiar por un `char`, una vez tiene lo que obtienes en una variable simplemente para que le asignes una función lo metes en un `if`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a;
    a = getch();

    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```